# How to load pictures from project resources automatically with a 5 second delay?

Tags: c#, timer, delay, picturebox

Can anyone help me, how can i load pictures from my project resources.
And load them one by one into a picturebox after each other with a 5 secs delay using C# from app?

Comment: what will you do next? programmers are waiting

Comment: This is way too broad of a question. Try breaking your problem down into smaller sections, try some code, and if you have specific questions about parts of code that aren't working, we would be happy to help. As it stands, this question is far too broad to be answered

Answer (score 0):

For the delay you can use this code:

```
//5000 means 5 seconds
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

And for Loading you can use this:

```
Picturebox1.Image = Image.FromFile("image address");
```